# Add another key php array json

Tags: php

Please correct the terminologies that I am using.

I am trying to return a json data like this:

```
"data": [
{
    "id": 1
    "name": "test"
},
{
{
    "id": 2
    "name": "abc"
},
{
    "id": 3
    "name": "zxc"
}
]
```

and my code is exactly this one

```
$data = [];

foreach($prices as $price) {
    $data[]["id"] = $price->id;
    $data[]["name"] = $price->name;
}

$result["data"] = $data;
```

the code returns the json like this:

```
"data": [
{
    "id": 1
},
{
    "name": "test"
}
{
    "id": 2
},
{
    "name": "abc"
}
{
    "id": 3
},
{
    "name": "zxc"
}
]
```

Sorry for the bad formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this

```
foreach($prices as $price) {
    $data[] = [
        "id"=> $price->id,
        "name" => $price->name
     ];
}
```

You are adding the items sequentially, when you need to group them in an array and then add that array as a single unit.

Answer (score 2):

```
$i = 0;
$data = [];

foreach($prices as  $price) {
  $data[$i]["id"] = $price->id;
  $data[$i]["name"] = $price->name;
  $i++;
}


$result["data"] = $data;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you keep appending to the array instead of appending to an object and *then* to the `$data` array.

Try like this

```
$data = [];

foreach($prices as $price) {
    $topush = [];
    $topush["id"] = $price->id;
    $topush["name"] = $price->name;
    $data[] = $toReturn;
}

$result["data"] = $data;
```

or, even shorter

```
$data = [];

foreach($prices as $price) {
    $data[] = ['id' => $price->id, 'name' => $price->name];
}

$result["data"] = $data;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are adding two new Elements to your output, one containing the key/value for `id` and the other one for `name`. You have to put both into one element:

```
$data[]["id"] = $price->id; // Add one element
$data[]["name"] = $price->name; // Add second element

// New
$data[] = ['id' => $price->id, 'name' => $price->name]; // Add both as one Element
```

Answer (score 0):

Empty `[]` creates new index every time. You must specify index where you wish to insert:

```
$data = [];

foreach($prices as $i => $price) {
    $data[$i]["id"] = $price->id;
    $data[$i]["name"] = $price->name;
}

$result["data"] = $data;
```

Answer (score 0):

You kept assigning the value to a new key you should assign the data you want bundle in one go.

```
$data = [];

foreach($prices as $price) {
    $data[] = [
        "id" => $price->id,
        "name" => $price->name;
    ]
}

$result["data"] = $data;
```